# How to get the rank of inverse document frequency (idf value) fof all the terms of my corpus from sklearn TfidfVectorizer()?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

Which is the most efficient way to obtain a dataFrame with all the terms of my corpus of documents in a column and only their IDFs values ranked in another column ?

Since now i've only been able to get the dataFrame with the whole TF-IDF values in the following way:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# sum tfidf frequency of each term through documents
sums = X.sum(axis=0)

# connecting term to its sums frequency
data = []
for col, term in enumerate(terms):
    data.append( (term, sums[0,col] ))

ranking = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['term','rank'])
ranking = ranking.sort_values('rank', ascending=False)
```

So when printing `ranking` i got

```
term    tf-idf
a       2744.221862
b       2307.054479
c       2157.986107
d       1847.079024
e       1709.869790
...     ...
```

How can i do it similarly to obtain the same dataFrame but with only IDF values?

Comment: This is not possible using sklearn, but nothing prevents you from computing this manually

Comment: Yes i did it manually but it's not efficient for the amount of data I got.